# PostgreSQL subquery as usable variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use a subquery that comes out into a column in another calculation later on. How can I do this?

```
SELECT c_id, c_title, c_enrolcap,
(SELECT COUNT(e_id) AS enrol FROM enrollments WHERE e_c_id = c_id) AS enrolled,
c_enrolcap - enrolled AS avail,
FROM classes AS c
```

So basically what comes out of `enrolled` I need this as a column to calculate off of later and also as it's own column.

Comment: Is the above query expected to return a single row or multiple rows?

Comment: Multiple rows, many rows to be exact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually do this with Common Table Expressions.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

Do the `c_enrolcap - enrolled as avail` in the outer query.

Like:

```
WITH enrollment AS (
SELECT c_id, c_title, c_enrolcap,
(SELECT COUNT(e_id) AS enrol FROM enrollments WHERE e_c_id = c_id) AS enrolled

FROM classes AS c)
SELECT c_id, c_title, c_enrolcap, enrolled, c_enrolcap - enrolled AS avail
FROM enrollment
```